# Load a conditional .phtml file in a block of layout xml file (ex. based on product SKU)

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

Extreme newbie to Magento and php.

I want to set a different phtml based on the product in a block of my `catalog.xml` layout.

Basically, for normal products i want to load the usual `text.phtml` file in a block of my `category.xml` layout
(`catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml`, the one that shows custom text options) 

But a particular product, I want the same block to load, say,`different_text.phtml` (`catalog/product/view/options/type/different_text.phtml`) 


Is there a way to load a different phtml fle in a block on the basis of the SKU of the product?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to keep one template and separate the content to display inside the template, small example here that uses a sample product id *10*:

```
<?php $_option = $this->getOption(); ?>
<?php $p = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php if($p->getId != 10): ?>
<dt><label<?php if ($_option->getIsRequire()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($_option->getIsRequire()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo  $this->escapeHtml($_option->getTitle()) ?></label>
    <?php echo $this->getFormatedPrice() ?></dt>
<dd<?php if ($_option->decoratedIsLast){?> class="last"<?php }?>>
    <div class="input-box">
    <?php if ($_option->getType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_FIELD): ?>
        <input type="text" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()" id="options_<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>_text" class="input-text<?php echo $_option->getIsRequire() ? ' required-entry' : '' ?> <?php echo $_option->getMaxCharacters() ? ' validate-length maximum-length-'.$_option->getMaxCharacters() : '' ?> product-custom-option" name="options[<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getDefaultValue()) ?>" />
    <?php elseif ($_option->getType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_AREA): ?>
        <textarea id="options_<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>_text" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()" class="<?php echo $_option->getIsRequire() ? ' required-entry' : '' ?> <?php echo $_option->getMaxCharacters() ? ' validate-length maximum-length-'.$_option->getMaxCharacters() : '' ?> product-custom-option" name="options[<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>]" rows="5" cols="25"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getDefaultValue()) ?></textarea>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($_option->getMaxCharacters()): ?>
        <p class="note"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Maximum number of characters:')?> <strong><?php echo $_option->getMaxCharacters() ?></strong></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</dd>
<?php else: ?>
    display something else
<?php endif; ?>
```

That would be the quick n' dirty way :-)

The longer, more complex but professional way is to write your own extension with a block class that extends the current block class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Text` and decide inside your new block class which template you want to load based on product id or sth. else.